# Robocopy for only deltas in a certain time frame

Tags: powershell, network-share, robocopy

Is there a way to utilize Robocopy to target only files/folders that were modified within a certain time range? For example, if there is a file share with n-number of folders/files dating back several years, how would I target only the ones that were modified within the last one month or so and have the deltas copied over? I do not want it iterating throughout the entire share during the Robocopy process, but only targeting the recently changed files.

Comment: What's wrong on the `/MAXAGE:n` parameter? (MAXimum file AGE - _exclude_ files _older than_ `n` days/date.)

Comment: But does it iterate through every file to find that age?

Answer (score 0):

From the robocopy docs:

```
/MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
/MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
/MAXLAD:n :: MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n.
/MINLAD:n :: MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n.
             (If n < 1900 then n = n days, else n = YYYYMMDD date).
```

if you needed to get files that were accessed in the last month you would use:

```
robocopy <source_dir> <destination_dir> /MAXLAD:30 /S /Z /B
```